# How much memory is allocated to an object of this class?

Tags: c++, memory-management

In an object of this example class

```
class example
{
public:
    int x;
}
```

an object would be allocated 4 bytes of memory. As an int would take 4 bytes.

How much memory would be allocated to an object of the following class -

```
class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *prev, *next;
};
```

The int would take four bytes, but what about the 'next' and 'prev' pointers? What about the total size of an object of the class?

Comment: Why don't you find out with `sizeof`?

Comment: This question is too broad because, basically, every natural number could used as an answer to this question. The standard doesn't specify the size of the primitive types. It's implementation dependent. Use `sizeof` and learn about padding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The total size of the object is `sizeof(int) + 2*sizeof(node*) +` any padding the compiler might add between the members. Using `sizeof(node)` is the only portable and reliable way to find that out.

Answer (score -2):

Pointers are of size 4 bytes on x86 system or 8 bytes on x64 system.

So your total size of `node` is 4 + 4 + 4 or 4 + 8 + 8 which is 12 bytes on x86 architecture, or 20 bytes on x64 architecture.

Because of padding however, on x64 architecture, the actual size of the class will be 24 bytes, because x64 architecture requires 8 byte alignment.

As mentioned by Oliver Charlesworth, you can also do `std::cout << sizeof(node) << "\n";`, which will tell you the exact size of class node

Comment: `int` is *not* 8 bytes on most x64 compilers.  Also, this answer doesn't take padding into account.

Comment: The right answer is that it's implementation dependent. Try guessing what the system OP is useless.

Comment: I said on x86 or x64. Added padding into x64, on x86 the size is unchanged, because 12 bytes is 4 byte aligned