# How much memory does an initial empty unordered_map use?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

If I declare a hashmap like this:

```
std::unordered_map <int, int> m;
```

before I put anything in, how much memory is actually allocated for the map?

Comment: do `sizeof(m)` and find out

Comment: I believe that is implementation-defined, but probably not a lot. How much is too much for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194231/how-much-memory-is-allocated-to-an-object-of-this-class

Comment: @user253751 If the constructor allocates on the heap, would I see that with sizeof?

Comment: No, but probably the constructor does not allocate until you put some things in the map.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120861/how-to-measure-memory-usage-from-inside-a-c-program

Comment: @harold How much does it allocate?

Comment: @IsaacD.Cohen I don't know, the code is unreadable (as standard library code usually is), and on second look maybe I was wrong anyway

Comment: Neither stdlibc++ nor stdc++ seem to allocate anything on the heap. I don't know about MSVC's implementation. In any case, the answer is "it's implementation defined".

Comment: @Nelfeal msvc [does allocate a sentinel node at default construction](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/e28f9561233a58d48d893094ed3a6bc0c5ee6ad9/stl/inc/xtree#L883).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's implementation defined, but you can observe the memory usage for any given implementation you're using with a combination of `sizeof` (for the `unordered_map` object itself), and a custom allocator policy that documents dynamic allocation requests.

I coded that up on godbolt - https://godbolt.org/z/eoGfvv4zf - just writing as minimal a custom allocator as proved necessary to get it to run under the newest versions of gcc, clang and msvc.  The code's below too for reference.

As of 2022/12/29, it shows `sizeof` 64 for the gcc 12 and clang 15, which don't ask the allocator for extra memory until an insertion is done, while msvc v19 has `sizeof 40` and does ask the allocator for extra memory even when empty, with 80 bytes allocated (plus any management overheads the memory allocation library might have):

`allocate(1 struct std::_List_node<struct std::pair<int const ,int>,void *> == 16 bytes)`
`allocate(16 class std::_List_unchecked_iterator<class std::_List_val<struct std::_List_simple_types<struct std::pair<int const ,int> > > > == 64 bytes)`

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct my_allocator {
    my_allocator() = default;
    template< class U >
    constexpr my_allocator( const my_allocator<U>& other ) noexcept { }
    using Base = std::allocator<T>;
    Base base;
    using value_type = typename Base::value_type;
    T* allocate(std::size_t n, const void* hint) {
        return allocate(n);
    }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr T* allocate(std::size_t n) {
        std::cout << "allocate(" << n << ' ' << typeid(T).name()
        << " == " << n * sizeof(T) << " bytes)\n";
        return base.allocate(n);
    }
    constexpr void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n) {
        base.deallocate(p, n);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, int, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, my_allocator<std::pair<const int, int>>> m;
    std::cout << "sizeof " << sizeof m << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
        m[i] = i;
    std::cout << "buckets: " << m.bucket_count() << '\n';
}
```